# Directory.GetFiles returning entire path, I only want the filename?

Tags: vb.net, file, path, directory

This is the code I have set up to scan a directory of files:

```
Dim fileArray() As String
fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "help\")
```

And it successfully gets all files in the directory, but it gets their absolute paths aswell. For example, one of the entries in `fileArray()` is:

```
F:\Project\Project\bin\x86\Debug\help\book_troubleshoot.html
```

And I want it to just be:

```
book_troubleshoot.html
```

Is there a way to do this without parsing through all the array entries to trim off the path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

```
string filename= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpathname);
```